# Inverse of Thales' theorem in non euclidean Geometry?

Tags: geometry

I know that Thales' theorem is only true for semi-euclidean geometries, i.e. in every neutral geometry for which the angle sum of a triangle equals two right angles. In particular it is true for euclidean geometry, but not true for hyperbolic geometry.

I'm wondering about the inverse of Thales' theorem. It is true for euclidean geometry as the proof in wikipedia shows:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27_theorem#Proof_of_the_converse_using_geometry

I'm wondering if it is still true in hyperbolic geometry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To disprove a statement it is enough to present a counterexample.**

The hyperbolic right triangle below has the right angle at the doubly circled blue point. The red lines are the perpendicular bisectors to the sides. These red lines are concurrent, however they do not meet on the hypotenuse.
(I used the Klein model.)

[image]

Comment: I suppose geodesic lines in hyperbolic geometry cannot in all models be drawn by Ruler and Compass  as in euclidean construction.

Comment: @Narasimham: What is a ruler and what is a compass? In the Klein model you can use Euclidean ruler but you cannot use Euclidean compass. However, you can use hyperbolic compass and hyperbolic ruler. (Even if you do not have anything like that at hand.) This is true in general. Moral: There is no ruler or compass without telling the kind. This is why my second answer to the question above is much much better than the one giving an answer tied to a model. Why? Because it is independent of any model.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to give here a direct proof that the reverse Thales' theorem cannot be true in hyperbolic geometry.

Let the angle at $A$ equal $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Then, let's assume that the  $\color{red}{\text{perpendicular bisectors}}$ meet on the hypotenuse at the point $\color{red}{\circ}$ as shown in the figure below. If one connects $A$ and $\color{red}{\circ}$ with a $\color{blue}{\text{segment}}$ then the one gets two isosceles triangles. ($AC\color{red}{\circ}$ and $AB\color{red}{\circ}$)

[image]

At the point $A$ the angle is $\frac{\pi}{2}=\alpha+\beta$. So the sum of the angles of such a triangle is $\pi$. The geometry in which this happens cannot be hyperbolic.

Note: The fact that the base angles of an isosceles triangle equal is an absolute fact, i. e. it is true even in the hyperbolic geometry.